# Monthly payments (with annual growth rate) based on defined amount and expected return

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out the starting monthly amount that I would have to invest in order to get $1000 at the end of the 3rd year with an expected return of 8%, whereby by monthly payment would be growing by 2% every year.

The payments are being made at the end of the month.

I'm familiar with the concept of using the sum of geometric series to find the final value defined as:
$$S=R\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$
where $R$ is the constant payment, $r$ is the monthly return factor and $n$ is the number of months.

Based on that it is easy to find $R$ given other variables, but what if $R$ is growing by 2% every 12 months?

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to use the geometric series to approch this. But as you noticed, it only works for the same added monthly value to be correct.

So to get around that, compute the values for each year separately. Thus, use the geometric series for the first year with $R$, for the second year with $R\cdot 1.02$ and so on.

If you do so, note that $n$, the number of applicable months will be reduced by 12 for the second year and so on.

If you write out the sum of all years, you will be able to rewrite some terms to compute $R$.

I hope this approach helps, if you need more details, I will fill them out.

Comment: Thank you! I used your advice to come up with a general solution.